# SQL Insert into and Select multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, sql-insert

So I have a tables that look something like this:

Communication: (Calls made)

```
Timestamp            FromIDNumber ToIDNumber GeneralLocation 
2012-03-02 09:02:30  878          674        Grasslands 
2012-03-02 11:30:01  456          213        Tundra 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  789          654        Mountains
2012-03-02 08:06:08  458          789        Tundra
```

And I want to create a new table that has all the distinct `FromIDNumber` and `ToIDNumber`'s.

This is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0135c) for it.

This works:

```
INSERT INTO CommIDTemp (`ID`)
SELECT DISTINCT Communication.FromIDNumber
FROM Communication
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT DISTINCT Communication.ToIDNumber
FROM Communication;
```

and I got:

```
 ID  
 878
 456
 789
 674
 213
 654
 365
```

But I wonder if there is more efficient way, because the dataset that I have has millions and millions of lines and I didn't know about the performance of `UNION DISTINCT`.

I originally tried something like

```
INSERT INTO CommIDTemp (`ID`) 
SELECT DISTINCT Communication.FromIDNumber
AND Communication.ToIDNumber 
FROM Communication;
```

but that didn't work... is there any other way to do this more efficiently? I'm pretty new to SQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: `A and B` will try to insert the logical `AND` result of two strings.  `select 'a' and 'b'` -> result = `0`.

Comment: This is a one-time task?  So it does not really matter how long it takes?  What will you do about adding new values as more data comes in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing: I do not have experience with this big tables. So you have to test out the following tipps yourself to find out if they are really working in your situation:

**1.** Create index in the source table

Make sure that both columns `FromIDNumber` and `ToIDNumber` have an index, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE Communication ADD INDEX (FromIDNumber);
ALTER TABLE Communication ADD INDEX (ToIDNumber);
```

**2.** Try to remove `DISTINCT`

I could not find a faster query for your example, though you might try the query without the `DISTINCT` keyword - using `UNION` returns only distinct values by definition. So this SQL gives us the same result as your current query:

```
INSERT INTO CommIDTemp (`ID`)
SELECT FromIDNumber FROM Communication
UNION 
SELECT ToIDNumberFROM Communication;
```

**3.** Use a primary key in the temp table

Also try another approach by setting the CommIDTemp.ID column as a primary key and use `INSERT IGNORE` - this is especially useful if you want to update the table frequently without deleting the contents:

```
CREATE TABLE CommIDTemp (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT IGNORE INTO CommIDTemp (`ID`)
SELECT FromIDNumber FROM Communication
UNION
SELECT ToIDNumber FROM Communication;
```

Comment: `UNION` defaults to `DISTINCT`, so that won't make any difference.  The other option is `UNION ALL`, but that may give you duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Performance is mainly going to depend on how the table is indexed.  I don't see a way to do everything in one pass so I would suggest separate indexes on FromIDNumber and ToIDNumber.  That should make each statement in your union very fast even for a lot of rows.

You can make this faster by only using one `DISTINCT` statement.  Each`DISTINCT` requires a sort/temp table. You can drop the `DISTINCT` from each statement and the `UNION DISTINCT` will make sure you get distinct values.

```
INSERT INTO CommIDTemp (`ID`)
SELECT Communication.FromIDNumber
FROM Communication
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT Communication.ToIDNumber
FROM Communication;
```

Side Note:  `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION DISTINCT` but based on your requirements you need `UNION DISTINCT` which can be written as simply `UNION`.